# Work done by a particular force on a particle in one dimension

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I've been working on this problem a while.

I am supposed to prove that, for a particle of mass $m$, which is subject to a force $\vec{F}$ = $-av^2\vec{\hat{v}}$, (with $a$ a positive constant) the total work done in one-dimension as the particle moves a distance $b$ is:

$W = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2(e^{-2ab/m} - 1)$

where $v_0$ is the initial velocity.

I have obtained an equation for $v$ in terms of the direction $x$, which I think is right.

$v = e^{-ax/m}$

so $F = -ae^{-2ax/m}\vec{\hat{v}}$ and $d\vec{s} = dx$. Using all this, I get a similar answer but without the $v_0^2$. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think $v = e^{-ax/m}$

Comment: I get an expression of the form $\frac{-av}{m} = \frac{dv}{dx}$ and move the $v$ to the RHS whilst moving the $dx$ to the LHS. Then I integrate and take the $e$ of both sides to remove the natural log.

Comment: WAIT! When $x = 0$, $v$ will obviously equal $v_0$, so the real expression for $v$ should be $v = v_0e^{-ax/m}$. Squaring that, as is required, gives the correct solution.

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: Yes, sometimes we just need someone else to ask the right question. Thank you, MyGlasses.

Comment: Thanks God! Your welcome.